# Essential Mongo Wrapper Functionality

Tags: mongodb, wrapper, labview

I am writing a MongoDB wrapper interface for LabVIEW 2013 SP1 (32-bit).  I would like some help assembling a comprehensive set of wrapper methods to implement.  Do you know of a readily helpful resource that would define such a set?  I'm working through the manual right now (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/), which is useful enough, but I was hoping for something a little more concise.

Comment: [The reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/) might be a better starting point.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good.  Would you mind posting it as an answer?

Comment: No, because [a link doesn't fulfill the criteria for a complete answer on Stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: You could describe how you found the link, what you found useful, and perhaps others reviews of the content in the link.  Would that more fulfill the criteria for the complete answer?